# Simplifying the Summation of Summations: $ \sum_{n = 0}^{w}({ \sum_{k = n}^{2n} (k) })$

Tags: summation

My question is about the simplification of the following summation: $\sum_{n = 0}^{w}({ \sum_{k = n}^{2n} (k) })$.

I have used [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=summation%20from%20n%20%3D%200%20to%20w%20(%20summation%20from%20k%20%3D%20n%20to%202n%20(k))) and obtained that $ \sum_{n = 0}^{w}({ \sum_{k = n}^{2n} (k) }) = \frac{1}{2} w (w + 1) (w + 2)$. Even though this is all I originally needed to know for the problem, I am curious to know how this simplification is actually done because I don't quite understand it. (I think it just surpasses my current mathematical knowledge).

Could anyone explain this to me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using :
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
We get :
$$\sum_{n = 0}^{w}{ \sum_{k = n}^{2n} k }=\sum_{n = 0}^{w}\left(\sum_{k = 0}^{2n} k -\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} k \right)=\sum_{n = 0}^{w}\left(\frac{(2n+1)2n}{2} -\frac{n(n-1)}2 \right)\\=\frac32\sum_{n = 0}^{w}n^2  +\frac32\sum_{n = 0}^{w}n\\=\frac32\left(\frac{w(w+1)(2w+1)}{6}+\frac{w(w+1)}{2}\right)\\=\frac32w(w+1)\frac12\left(\frac{2w+1}{3}+1\right)\\=\frac14w(w+1)(2w+4)\\=\frac12w(w+1)(w+2)$$

Comment: I think you mean $-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}k$ in the middle of the first line.

Comment: oops yes ${}{}$

Comment: Thanks a lot! My issue was that I did not think about the two formulas you've used.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we can deal with the inside sum separately.

$\sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{i+n} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{i} + \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n(n+1) = \frac{3}{2}n(n+1).$

Therefore, the original sum reduces to $\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{w}{n^2 + n}$.

Using the equation for the sum of the first $w$ squares, we have:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{w}{n^2+n} = \frac{w(w+1)(2w+1)}{6} + \frac{w(w+1)}{2}$$

Simplifying, this reduces to $\frac{w(w+1)(w+2)}{3}$.

Bringing back in the leading factor of $3/2$ yields the final result of:
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{w}{\sum_{k=n}^{2n}{k}}  = \frac{1}{2} w(w+1)(w+2)$$

Comment: Thank you! Even though I've already accepted someone else's answer, yours is correct and helpful as well so I've accepted it too! Edit: I didn't because I can't accept two answers?

Comment: Quite welcome. You can only accept one. I recommend @Jennifer's answer; it is more complete.

Comment: Done! And again, thanks.